# Multiple testWidgets tests are not working in flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I'm using google flutter integration driver to automate the flutter mobile app.

I want to write multiple widgetTests in a single `main_test.dart` file.

First test is running successfully, but when second test starts i see `Test starting...`(attached screenshot below) screen in emulator, but actually not moving forward to launch the app screen.

[image]

And finally, getting below error saying that `Bad state: No element` as screen is not loaded.!

```html
Failure Details:
Failure in method: check value increments
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════
The following StateError was thrown running a test:
Bad state: No element

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Iterable.single (dart:core/iterable.dart:654:25)
#1      WidgetController.element (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:114:30)
#2      WidgetController.ensureVisible (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:1210:73)
#3      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/tummalacharlajagadeesh/Desktop/Sparrow/synapse-cards-mobile/synapse-cards-mobile/integration_test/sanity_test.dart:87:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is my integration test file `main_test.dart`:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:sparrowmobile/flavor/uat.dart' as app;


void main() {
  final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  binding.framePolicy = LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBindingFramePolicy.fullyLive;
  
  group('sanity test suite', () {
    //runs before each test
    setUp(() async {
      app.main();
    });

    //runs after each test
    tearDown(() async {
      final getIt = GetIt.instance;
      await getIt.reset();
    });

    testWidgets('sample test', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 5));

      // ensure title is visible
      await tester.ensureVisible(find.byKey(const ValueKey('startButton')));
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const ValueKey('startButton')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.text('Home Screen'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('Transactions'), findsOneWidget);
    });

    testWidgets('check value increments', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 10));

      //ensure title is visible
      await tester.ensureVisible(find.byKey(const ValueKey('startButton')));
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const ValueKey('startButton')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    });

  });
}
```

Can anybody help here me to run multiple widgetTests in a single file?